# Connecting PSW to motherboard ON/OFF pins

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, connector

I want to know is it possible to connect this PSW 2 pin connector to my motherboard:
[image: DC-DC converter]

my motherboard ( if yes please tell me where to plug it in )
[image: motherboard]

Comment: does anyone has any idea?

Comment: If you really want this power supply module to control the motherboard, then you will lose the "power switch" on the front of the PC case.  The connection would be to the "power switch" pins that are part of the "front panel" connector.  Consult the motherboard owner's manual for the layout of that header.

Comment: okay thank you.. that's what I wanted to hear..I don't need on/off switch. Can you write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want this power supply module to control the motherboard, then you will lose the "power switch" on the front of the PC case. The connection on the motherboard would be to the "power switch" pins that are part of the *front panel* connector. Consult the motherboard owner's manual for the layout (pin assignments) of that header.